# how to call a taskflow based on the outcome of dropdown in ADF.?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, adfs, adf-task-flow

I want to call a taskflow based on the outcome of Dropdown, I have a dropdown with LOV, if i choose a value in that, it should call the taskflow assigned to it. How to do that.?. How to assign a taskflow for all the values and how to call that. Somebody please help...

Comment: Is your task flow based on fragments or pages?

Comment: Based on .jsff extension.       Letz take a example that, I have a dropdown box with set of LOV. If i choose anyone value from LOV, it should take me to the page assigned to it. How to assign a page and how to do the redirection.?

Answer (score 1):

I would put this problem in a different perspective: what you are trying to do is to invoke an navigation action of the current task flow. This action can be firing a task flow call.

Presuming the current task flow has an action named "gotoTF1", action pointing towards a Task Flow Call activity, you should have an af:button with visible=false  and action="gotoTF1".

Please find below few blogs, explaining this in more detail:

http://www.techartifact.com/blogs/2012/09/queue-an-action-event-or-invoking-the-button-action-in-programmatic-way-techartifact.html#sthash.MIyX2mvt.dpbs
http://www.awasthiashish.com/2013/04/invoking-button-action.html
https://mjabr.wordpress.com/2011/05/20/invoke-buttons-action-programatically-in-java/

Comment: If im selecting a value in Dropdown, it should take me to the page desgined for it. how can i make this thing happen.With Task flow/Control flow or any other way.? Onselection of the DropDown value navigation to corresponding page(Which previously designed) for that value should happen.

Comment: How can i link the value of the dropdown to a Taskflow/Control flow.

Comment: You will register a ValueChangeListener to your dropdown and from there you will call button's action programatically. Please check second blog.
About task flow calls activities: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/b31974/taskflows_activities.htm#ADFFD1948

Comment: The problem, Since im new to this tool, i couldnt able to follow that document.. Can you please help me with some sample project.?

Comment: If you can point out what errors you've got and what did you tried already, maybe we may guide you further.

Comment: I found the solution.M getting all the options including Gantt chart when create it as a .jspx Fragment...  I dont know its de right solution, but issue fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the basics then you will not how to call a action from from button ?

Now you have to just use the code from blog to call that Action using ValueChangeEvent

Ashish